# Python cannot send email via iRedMail

Tags: python, starttls, iredmail

I have installed iRedEmail on my mail server. Now it has default certificate. When I use a normal email client, it asks me to TRUST certificate of the mail server and then it starts Receiving / Sending email from the mail server

But if I write my own python program to send email, then I don't know how to do the same like email clients. Currently python gives error "Server Configuration Problem"

```
SMTPserver = 'smtp.xxxx.com
SMTPport = 587
sender =     'info@xxx.com'
destination = ['testgmailid@gmail.com']

USERNAME = "info@xxxx.com"
PASSWORD = "1234"

text_subtype = 'plain'

subject="Sent from Python"

import sys
import os
import re

from smtplib import SMTP       
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

try:
    msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
    msg['Subject']=       subject
    msg['From']   = sender 

    conn = SMTP(SMTPserver,SMTPport)
    conn.set_debuglevel(True)
    conn.ehlo()
    conn.starttls()
    conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    try:
        conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
    finally:
        conn.close()

except Exception, exc:
    sys.exit( "mail failed; %s" % str(exc) ) # give a error message
```

Comment: Without your code, we can't really help you...

Comment: Sorry, added the coded. But it is not the code problem. It seems that the machine on which I am running the python code, I should add the certificate or somehow pass to python the certificate of mail server. I dont know

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that there were two services that were not running

Below are the two services. The moment the two services were started, the python program was able to send email. The first service is related to policy of postfix

I just typed the below command on the prompt

```
/etc/init.d/postfix-cluebringer restart
```

and also typed below command on the prompt

```
/etc/init.d/amavis restart
```